# How can color of a default parameter in call, be changed like PyCharm?

Tags: listings, python, sourcecode

I am working on a document that contains some Python codes.
I use the following template in Overleaf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%New colors defined below
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.97,0.97,0.97}
\definecolor{navy}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{teal}{rgb}{0,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}

%Code listing style named "mystyle"
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
  commentstyle=\color{darkgray},
  keywordstyle=\color{navy},
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
  stringstyle=\color{teal},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  breakatwhitespace=false,         
  breaklines=true,                 
  captionpos=b,                    
  keepspaces=true,                 
  numbers=left,                    
  numbersep=5pt,                  
  showspaces=false,                
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,                  
  tabsize=2
}

%"mystyle" code listing set
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\title{Code Listing}
\date{ }

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Code example}


%Python code highlighting
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=Python example]
def test(x1, x2=0):
    return min(x1, x2)

a = 1
b = 2
print(test(a, x2=b))

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The result is good. but I want to know is it possible to change the color of the parameter name when we call the function with a different value or not?

[image]

As you can see **x2** in the call has a different color in PyCharm and Latex. I defined the purple color that I like to use. But I don't know is there a setting for that in Python's lstlisting or not.

Comment: You can try the [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted?lang=en) package, which provides better syntax highlighting results.